# Replication PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, centos7, replication

I did the stream replication (Slave-Master) using postghreSQL 9.6 on Centos 7.

During the fail Over we promoted the Slave to become the new master.
Now we have solved the problem concerning the old master ,and we want to return to our old architecture where the old Master has to be the master and the new Master has to become the Slave.

When we try to turn new Master to Slave the replication is not working neither the Read-Only.

In fact we are facing challenges when making the new Master to become the Slave or to get to the initial state before the Fail Over.

Note:When we do replication,it just copy(*pg_basebackup*) data from one server to another ,when we make changes in the master it does not effect the Slave and the Slave still read and write what is not normal.

Is it possible that because of the Fail Over that the new Master Can't become Slave again ?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible if the "old master" was ahead of the promoted slave.

Either start from scratch with a new `pg_basebackup` or try to reset the old master with `pg_rewind`.

Of course you have to add an appropriately configured `recovery.conf`.

Comment: I have tried them all ,i have even re-installed postgreSQL 9.6 both (Master and Slave).The problem still the same,replication is not working.

Comment: I used this tutorial  :[replication ](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-master-slave-replication-with-postgresql-96-on-centos-7/ ) to configure the replication back then,but i 'm using the same tutorial now but the replication is not working. At the end of the day, it seems like the trigger is not doing what it supposed to.

Comment: This is the content of my **recovery.conf** in the Slave data directory:                                                                                                             `standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=30.30.1.145 port=5432 user=replica password=aqwe123@ application_name=pgslave01'
trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432' `

Comment: I guess there is a configuration error somewhere. Why don't you follow the official documentation instead of some tutorial?